# how to chain methods with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/ph12bbax/

i'm creating navigation bar and i want to `removeClass('active')` and `removeClass('border')`from inactive items. i was trying

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
     <li><a href="#"><span class="active">home</span><div class="border"></div></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><span>portfolio</span></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><span>contact</span></a></li>
  </ul>
```

JS

```
$('.navbar-nav > li > a ').on('click', function(){

$(this).children('span').addClass('active')
    .parent('a').append('<div class="border"></div>')
    .siblings().children('span').removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: and the problem you are having is .......

Comment: Check [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/ph12bbax/1/). Is this what you want?

Comment: i also want to remove '.border' class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ph12bbax/3/).

```
$('.navbar-nav > li > a ').on('click', function () {
$(this).append('<div class="border"></div>')
    .children('span').addClass('active').parents('li')
    .siblings('li').find('span').removeClass('active')
    .siblings('.border').remove();
});
```

Basically you are executing the function on `.navbar-nav > li > a`, so `$(this)` here represent `a`. Then:

1. you should append `.border` to it
2. then get `span` *children* of `$(this)` and add class `active` to it
3. then get *siblings* of `li` *parent*
4. then find *children* `span` and remove class `active`
5. then select `.border` *siblings* to remove it

Answer (score 1):

In simple Modification your can remove all active and border like below, before you add classes.

```
$('.navbar-nav > li > a ').on('click', function(){
     $('.navbar-nav > li > a span').removeClass('active'); // Remove active
    $('.navbar-nav > li > a div').removeClass('border'); // Remove border
    $(this).children('span').addClass('active')
        .parent('a').append('<div class="border"></div>')
        .siblings().children('span').removeClass('active');

    // and i also want to remove class border on inactive element
});
```

JsFiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/ph12bbax/5/